# iOS keyboard scrolling issue with webview

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll, webview, keyboard

My problem is my website has a iframe that pops up. When I click on a input box, the iOS keyboard pushes the iframe all the way up. See the demo gif.
http://cl.ly/image/1t2u2I3I0L0F

I want the keyboard to shift the page slightly up so that the user can see the input box while they are typing. This is a web view and I have no idea how to control the keyboard unless this is a native app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: It is not problem of webview but it problem of your webpage. for proper result your webpage must be responsive for size.

Comment: oh yeah it is responsive, both the site and the iframe/popup. The problem is that it pushes the iframe to the bottom. And I'm wondering if I can control that pushing. I only want to change code in that iframe.

Comment: Did you find something for this? I am also facing same issue

Comment: Are there any solutions of this yet??